# Server refuses SSH key provided by KeeAgent plugin of KeePass

Tags: ssh, putty, keepass

I am using KeePass2 and KeeAgent on Windows and attempting to connect to a Linux box using Putty and pscp.

I have configured KeeAgent per these instructions:

http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/usage/quick-start/

The key was originally generated on linux and copied to Windows.

When I connect to the Linux box using putty, I am prompted for a password.

In order to debug I installed pscp so I could run with the -v option to get debugging information.

Here is the output of pscp:

```
C:\Users\Marty>pscp -v marty@pluto.lan:opentp.sh .
Looking up host "pluto.lan"
Connecting to NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Using username "marty".
Trying Pageant key #0
Server refused our key
Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication request refused
marty@pluto.lan's password:
Sent password
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Fatal: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

What is a systematic way to debug this problem?

Comment: If you down cote my question, please have the courage to tell me why.  I want to be a good member of the community, but a down vote without an explanation does not help me refine my question or get better at asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you did not add a public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the server (as you did not mention that, neither the KeeAgent manual does).

Make sure you add public key as seen in PuTTYgen to the `authorized_keys` file.

See [Getting ready for public key authentication](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-gettingready) for details.

---

Note that you can see the log in PuTTY by right-clicking its window title and selecting the *Event Log*. You do not have to use pscp for this. See [The PuTTY Event Log](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-eventlog).